# How do I know what NETCDF version I have?

Tags: redhat, netcdf

I am currently on my research computer at my university. I don't have access to anyone til later in the week and need to know what version my NETCDF is. I am hoping it is NETCDF4 so I can recompile something easily.

I am using Red Hat.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ nc-config --version
```

gives

```
netCDF 4.3.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `ncdump -h <name of netcdf file>`

Comment: I know how to access the file, and I know it is netcdf but I need to know if I have NETCDF4 on here so I can save files as NETCDF4

Comment: If You just type `ncdump` then the last line in my system shows the version of NetCDF. But unless Your system is ancient, it definitely has NetCDF4 support, could be a bit outdated though.